# Prove: If a linear map, $φ: U→V$ is bijective, then $φ(x)=0$ has only the solution $x=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove: If a linear map, $φ: U→V$  is bijective, then $φ(x)=0$ has only the solution $x=0$.

Either a proof or explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that only injectivity is needed. Actually the fact that $\{x\in U:\varphi(x)=0\}=\{0\}$ is equivalent to injectivity of $\varphi$ (under the assumption $\varphi$ is linear, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $0 = 0x$ to determine $\varphi(0)$, then use the fact that $\varphi$ is bijective.

Comment: Ah, so that must be the only solution! Seems like a trivial question now! Thanks! :)

Comment: Problems always seem easier once you know the solution. You should try to prove the converse to this result. That is, if $\varphi : U \to V$ is a surjective linear map and $\varphi(x) = 0$ only has the solution $x = 0$, then $\varphi$ is a bijection.